# Content behind Position: fixed is intractable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have following setup:

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="element" id="first"></div>
   <div class="element"></div>
   <div class="element"></div>
   <div class="element"></div>
...
</div>
```

so wrapper is set to `overflow-x: auto` and content that overflows it is horizontally scrollable. `#first` div has fixed position and more styling applied, but essentially it is always visible and other divs scroll behind it, like this:

[image]

issue here is that I'm using drag and drop functionality which works fine, but once I try to drop stuff on a fixed div and if it has content behind it, the drag and drop happens to that content. Basically feels like I'm interacting with stuff behind fixed div even though it is in front. I know fixed elements are out of the flow and maybe this is whats causing it? But I can't figure out how to make content behind that div stay behind it.

Comment: I am not fully sure what the problem is.. can you show your Javascript please? If you using `on('mouseclick' .. )` try using `on('mouseenter' ..)`. Also is the other content marked with a higher `z-index`?

Comment: Creating an working example of the problem would help. Code snippet or jsfiddle?

Comment: Add your full code example please (HTML/CSS/Javascript). http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... It maybe because fixed elements are out of the flow.

You can try setting the element with id first as absolute and giving it a high z-index value. A high value of z-index will make it stay on top of other elements.
So when others scroll it will remain at that position.

Answer (score 0):

Try plaing with ay `pointer-events: none;` in CSS